# ShellExecute print from stream instead of file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

With this

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'print', PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'Test.txt'), 
   nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
```

It is possible to print out files.

Is there a way I can use a `TStream` instead of a file so that I can print directly from my stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use `ShellExecute` to print from a Delphi stream. The call to `ShellExecute` will result in a different process performing the printing operation. And that different process cannot see your Delphi stream.

A couple of options spring to mind:

1. Save the stream to a temporary file, and print that using `ShellExecute`.
2. Print the text directly from Delphi. One quick and dirty method would be to add the text to a `TRichEdit` and call its [`Print`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Print) method. Andreas Rejbrand has more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809478/help-needed-about-printing-text-file-with-delphi/6810708#6810708).

Comment: ok thx i am allready using your suggested solution (saving to a tamporary file)